# PyQt Countdown timer - starter from another app by socket connection

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6

I want to create a countdown timer app in python. 
I'v created a timer in PyQt, and now I wan't to set time to count and start this timer from another app by send signal and val by socket connection.

This is my code. Gui was generated in QtCreator

Server.py

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import datetime

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

from serwer_gui import Ui_MainWindow


class MyForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # Syglany i sloty
        self.ui.pushButtonKlientClose.clicked.connect(self.close_client)
        self.ui.pushButtonCzasStart.clicked.connect(self.start_count)

    def close_client(self):
        c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        c.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
        c.send("zamknij;".encode())
        c.close()
        return

    def start_count(self):
        ilosc_minut = self.ui.spinBoxTime.value()
        print(ilosc_minut)
        c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        c.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
        c.send(("czas_set;10").encode())
        c.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and Client.py

```
import socket
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

from klient_gui import Ui_MainWindow


class MyForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # Pelen ekran
        # self.showFullScreen()
        self.showMaximized()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.polaczenie = Polaczenie(self)
        self.polaczenie.start()
        #self.start_linczik(20)

    def updateLCD(self):
        # Update the lcd
        self.start_time -= 1
        if self.start_time >= 0:
            self.ui.lcdNumber.display("%d:%02d" % (self.start_time / 60, self.start_time % 60))
        else:
            self.timer.stop()

    def start_linczik(self, b):
        self.start_time = b
        self.ui.lcdNumber.display("%d:%02d" % (self.start_time / 60, self.start_time % 60))
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateLCD)

class Polaczenie(QtCore.QThread):
    sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str,str)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Polaczenie, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = parent.ui
        self.parent = parent
        self.sig.connect(self.event_dispatcher)

    def run(self):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        ip = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 1234
        adress = (ip, port)
        server.bind(adress)
        server.listen(1)

        while True:
            print("Start listenint on ", ip, " on ", port)
            (client, addr) = server.accept()
            print("Got connection from ", addr[0], ":", addr[1])
            data = client.recv(1024)
            data = data.decode()
            print("Recived ", data, " from the client")
            print("Processin data")
            indeks_srednik = data.index(";")
            instrukcja = data[:indeks_srednik]
            try:
                string = data[indeks_srednik+1:]
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            try:
                print(instrukcja)
                print(string)
                if instrukcja == "zamknij":
                    # Zamykanie aplikacji przy pomocy serwera
                    server.close()
                    sys.exit(0)
                elif instrukcja == "czas_set":
                    self.sig.emit("czas_set", string)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    def event_dispatcher(self, a, b):
        # funkcja dispatchujaca eventy
        if a == "czas_set":
            print("licznik start")
            print(a)
            print(b)
            b=int(b)
            MyForm().start_linczik(b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What i want to achieve is situation when I send to klient.py message via socket(ex. czas_set;60) from server.py, and after that klient.py set time to countdown, and start countdown.
Right now when I run my program, I can send messege, but timer don't start. Only app is freezing and fail.
When I start timer from **init** from MyForm class timer works correct. It only fail when I want to run it via socket from another thred
What I do wrong? How can I fix this situatuion?

Tested on Windows 7 and python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused because running `MyForm().Start_linczik(b)` is creating another window, and this window will create a server with the same port, which generates the error since the port is busy.

What you should do is call the function `start_linczik` with the existing object, for this we can use signals, or as in this case I will show the use of `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` but for this you must use the decorator [`pyqtSlot()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSlot) in the slot, this has advantage reduce memory consumption and make the application a little faster.

```
class MyForm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        [...]

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def updateLCD(self):
        [...]

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def start_linczik(self, b):
        [...]
```

it is not necessary to save the `parent` or `parent.ui` in a variable since you can access the parent through the `parent()` method.

```
class Polaczenie(QtCore.QThread):
    sig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str,str)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Polaczenie, self).__init__(parent)
        self.sig.connect(self.event_dispatcher)

    def run(self):
        [...]

    def event_dispatcher(self, a, b):
        # funkcja dispatchujaca eventy
        if a == "czas_set":
            print("licznik start")
            print(a)
            print(b)
            b=int(b)
            #MyForm().start_linczik(b)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.parent(), "start_linczik", 
                QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection, QtCore.Q_ARG(int, b))
```

Comment: I added Your sugest to code but app still does not work. Still I have the same issue - app freezed and fail. Here I have some info from running app, and as You said it looks like app try to open second connection and listen also.   
    C:\Users\nyslay\PycharmProjects\klient\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
    C:/Users/nyslay/PycharmProjects/klient/main.py
    Start listenint on  127.0.0.1  on  1234
    Got connection from  127.0.0.1 : 49858
    Recived  czas_set;10  from the client
    Processin data
    czas_set
    10
   Start listenint on  127.0.0.1  on  1234
licznik start
czas_set
10

Comment: @DawidRespondek Maybe I have not implemented my solution completely, in the following link is the complete code https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/fc9e7efaa5a51d5af1c98f7a1e0d6a5c

Comment: @DawidRespondek First run Client.py and then just run Server.py